# Get inserted primary key in MS SQL before COMMIT

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In PHP I'm trying to insert multiple rows into two separate tables.  Because these all need to succeed, I'm starting with:

```
mssql_query("BEGIN TRAN");
```

Then I run through the insert into the main table:

```
$insert_Proposal = 'INSERT INTO PROPOSALS( ';

$insert_Proposal .= 'ApprovedByDev, ';
$insert_Proposal .= 'EstFundingEndFiscalYear, ';
$insert_Proposal .= 'EstFundingStartDate, ';
$insert_Proposal .= 'ProjectDesc, ';
$insert_Proposal .= 'ProjectType, ';
$insert_Proposal .= 'ProposalComments ';

$insert_Proposal .= ') VALUES ( ';

$insert_Proposal .= sqlSafeVars($_POST['ApprovedByDev'], "varchar") .', '; 
$insert_Proposal .= sqlSafeVars($_POST['EstFundingEndFiscalYear'], "bigint") .', '; 
$insert_Proposal .= sqlSafeVars($_POST['EstFundingStartDate'], "varchar") .', '; 
$insert_Proposal .= sqlSafeVars($_POST['ProjectDesc'], "varchar") .', '; 
$insert_Proposal .= sqlSafeVars($_POST['ProjectType'], "bigint") .', '; 
$insert_Proposal .= sqlSafeVars($_POST['ProposalComments'], "varchar") .' '; 

$insert_Proposal .= ')';
```

What I need is to get the autonumbered ProposalID that will be created by this so I can use it to insert records into the other table, before I issue the **COMMIT**

I've found suggestions to use something like:

```
output inserted.pk
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Joe');
SELECT ID AS LastID FROM Persons WHERE ID = @@Identity;
```

But these don't seem to work if you aren't committing the initial transaction.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think the problem is in using an autonumber; you have to use an identity in the table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661998/oracle-sequence-but-then-in-ms-sql-server

Comment: I'm only the web programmer on this one, no DBA priviledges, so I can make suggestions, but I have to live with the structure they provide.  That said, when I said autonumber, I did mean it is defined as an identity with an Identity Increment of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solution, using OUTPUT clause or using SCOPE_IDENTITY, should work just fine even if you started a transaction. But I don't see any of them actually used in the code you posted. The OUTPUT clause must be attached to the very INSERT you write, something like:

```
$insert_Proposal = 'INSERT INTO PROPOSALS( ';
$insert_Proposal .= 'ApprovedByDev, ';
...
$insert_Proposal .= ') ';
$insert_Proposal .= 'OUTPUT INSERTED.id '
$insert_Proposal .= ' VALUES ( ';
$insert_Proposal .= sqlSafeVars($_POST['ApprovedByDev'], "varchar") .', '; 
...
$insert_Proposal .= ')';
```

and you need to execute $insert_Proposal as a statement that *returns results*.

Comment: I had originally posted an answer with SELECT IDENT_CURRENT because I thought the SCOPE_IDENTITY did not generate the value until after the commit... but researching I have since found that it generates the new ID when the insert begins whether it's rolled back or not.  So, deleted my answer and voted yours up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666536/sql-server-scope-identity-thread-safety

Comment: Thanks Remus, I was putting the OUTPUT in the wrong place.  It did indeed reserve the Primary Key even though I hadn't committed the query.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), since it returns the last inserted identity within the current session and scope. A scope can be a batch, stored procedure, function or trigger.